# Is this an error in the Quasi-Newton condition slide?

Tags: optimization

The confusing part is at [this point](https://youtu.be/H6CCJ5c3WQw?list=PL6EA0722B99332589&t=532) in the lecture from the Numerical Optimization course.

---

Consider a simple way to update $B^k$: Let $a \neq 0, u \in R, u \neq 0$

$$B^{k+1} = B^k + \alpha uu^T$$

Choose a and u such that B^{k+1} satisfies the Quasi-Newton condition.

$$(B^k + \alpha u u^t)\gamma^k=\delta^k$$
$$\alpha u^t y^ku=\delta^k-B^k \gamma^k$$

---

$\alpha u^t y^ku$ definitely seems like the wrong way to rotate $\alpha u u^t\gamma^k$? Is that right or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\alpha u u^t\gamma^k = \alpha u (u^t\gamma^k) = \alpha (u^t\gamma^k) u = \alpha u^t\gamma^k u $$
because the quantity in parentheses, $(u^t\gamma^k)$, is a scalar, and therefore commutes with the vector $u$.

However, the lecturer does seem to have some strange ideas about SR1. For instance saying that the initial Hessian approximation must be positive definite.  And saying that it is a bad method because it does not necessarily obey heriditary positive definiteness.  On the contrary, the initial Hessian approximation need not be positive definite, and the value of SR1 is as an alternative to, for instance, BFGS, for situations in which the true Hessian may not be positive definite, and therefore SR1 might provide a better approximation, for optimization purposes, than a positive definite Hessian approximation.  However, in such case, SR1 should generally be used in conjunction with either a trust region method, or a line search method which searches along directions of negative curvature in the event that the Hessian approximation is not positive definite.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is correct, but I came with the impression that for the method to work the slope of the gradient needs improve after every update. I am not sure whether this will be covered in the course, but I know the BFGS cannot handle stochastic objectives and am wondering whether that extends to the rank one update? What happens if you try to use such methods with minibatch learning?

Comment: Things get very tricky when the gradient and/or objective function are evaluated subject to noise. BFGS tends to be "smoother" than SR1 in such cases, i.e., less buffeted by the noise.  BFGS can be damped to maintain hereditary positive definiteness if the dot product of the argument difference and gradient difference (your $\gamma^Ty$) is negative, as can easily happen when gradients are noisy. There are many other complications.